# Handlebars define a {{with}} in condition

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I want to show a different content from my json in my template depending of a javascript defined variable.

Here is the JSON file :

```
{
"normal" :{
    "content":"content"
}
"expert" :{
    "content":"content"
}
```

[HTML] Now in my template, I have this :

```
{{#with normal}}
    <p>{{content}}</p>
{{/with}}
```

Now I want to be able to use 'with normal', or 'with expert' depending of a javascript-side defined variable.

I have made a compare helper but, I have to use the code twice and that's ugly. So Maybe someone know how to do it properly ? Thanks.

Comment: U can just write a custom handlebars helper for this. But do u use handlebars without a MVC Framework (like ember.js)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need logic in your template?

If the body of the `{{#with}}` block is identical for data of `normal` or `expert` types, then you can probably get rid of the `with` entirely and pass the appropriate block into the template. This pushes the logic back into the script (and hopefully the view, if you have an MVC framework), which is good, and optimizes out a level of the template (also good, especially since that is a `with`, which tend to be slow).

Note that Handlebars is perfectly happy taking an object with *more* data than it needs, so writing a template that depends on the `normal` block and passing the `expert` with additional details (presumably) will cause no problems at all.

Comment: Oh, thank you, i didn't think about this solution and it works perfectly ! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use {{#if and else...
Also, you can make the handler global and use it twice.